# xcode not pre-filling for me

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, autocomplete, compiler-errors

I've just noticed that xcode is no longer prefilling for me. For instance I want to write

```
CGRectMake (self.frame.size.width, ...);
```

Xcode is not prefilling the .frame and so on. Not only this but if I write it, it gives me error and tells me

```
object 'frame' not found on...
```

I mean, what on earth happened here?. The code I had already written is alright, compiling and no problems.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it should be `self.view.frame` ?

Comment: What the ·$%$$@@  !!!  thanks dude!, I've been really spending too much hours in front of the computer...

Comment: I don't know what I am doing anymore.